# In Windows 10, how can I turn off Wifi in the router through a keyboard command?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My friend fears the Wireless section of her router being on all the time.

She wants to be able to turn the Wireless section off using a command on a computer connected by Ethernet.

Also, she wants to be able to turn the Wireless section ON occasionally so that her boyfriend's phone can use it.

The computer connected to the router by Ethernet must always have Internet access.

The router model is Linksys E1200.

Is there a Windows 10 command that would allow that?

Comment: She should just turn off the SSID beacon so that the wifi will only transmit when it's in use.

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Of what use is downvoting it if the downvoter doesn't explain why? Makes him/her feel superior? That's really pathetic...

Comment: You have a good question. I upvoted it

Comment: @RobertMiller Your problem is very poorly explained. Most of your question is focused on your proposed solution to the problem. We can't tell how to flesh out your solution because we don't understand what problem it's supposed to solve and, for the same reason, can't do a good job of proposing or explaining alternate solutions. Have a look at my first comment which might be the perfect solution to his actual problem ... or might not address it at all. As stated, the question is unanswerable because of this.

Comment: Robert - I took the liberty of editing your question to make it very clear to a reader. I trust this was OK to do.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done natively in Windows. And likely, your router does not accept an external command line.  Most do not.

Your friend can log into the Router Interface and turn Wireless on or off as necessary, or institute short hours of use for the Wireless to turn on at a specific time for a short time. Not all routers support this feature, but a number do support this.